# Php Find a word in text that starts with specific characters and make it a url link

Tags: php, regex

Hello what i am trying to do is find a word in text that starts with "pb" and make it a url

```
$message = 'test 123 message pb100000 message'
```

get the word pb100000 make it a hyperlink to [www.google.com/search=pb100000](http://www.google.com/search=pb100000) in html

What i have doen so far

```
echo preg_replace('/\bpd\S*gr/i', 
                  '<a href="https://www.google.com/search?br=${1}">Test</a>', 
                  'test 123 message pd100000gr message');
```

that makes an hyperlink under Test word, how can i make pd100000gr a hyperlink instead?

Comment: Use `/\bpb\d+/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With using anubhava solution in comments you can use like below in php.

```
echo preg_replace('/\b(pb\d+)/', 'www.google.com/search=${1}', 'test 123 message pb100000 message');
```

Comment: great answer thanks but what if i need to make pb100000 a hyperlink to  www.google.com/search=pb100000 insted?

Comment: @VlP3R then use <a href="www.google.com/search=${1}">www.google.com/search=${1}</a> instead of string

Comment: That prints:
"test 123 message www.google.com/search= message"

Comment: @VlP3R it will work when you render it on html, it is working for me in online ide, if not then try a new question with your current requirement.

Comment: Worked when i changed ${1} to ${0}